# How to add the items in a combobox into an array?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, swing, filtering

I have a combo box in my jform and I need an array to filter search results. I've made a separate class called user to get values from the table to an array.

```
package JAVA_VIDEOS_TUTORIALS;

public class User {

private int id;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private int age; //Combobox


public User(int Id,String Fname,String Lname,int Age)
{
    this.id = Id;
    this.fname = Fname;
    this.lname = Lname;
    this.age = Age;
}

public int getId()
{
    return id;
}

public String getFname()
{
    return fname;
}

public String getLname()
{
    return lname;
}

public int getAge()
{
    return age;
}
}
```

The JForm. Age is the combobox with values from 10 to 20 being shown for selection.

```
public class JTable_Search extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form JTable_Search
 */
public JTable_Search() {
    initComponents();

    // call findUsers function
    findUsers();

}


// function to connect to mysql database
public Connection getConnection()
{
    Connection con = null;

    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_db","root","");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return con;
}

// function to return users arraylist with particular data 
public ArrayList<User> ListUsers(String ValToSearch)
{
    ArrayList<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();

    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    try{
        Connection con = getConnection();
        st = con.createStatement();
        String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE CONCAT(`id`, `fname`, `lname`, `age`) LIKE '%"+ValToSearch+"%'";
        rs = st.executeQuery(searchQuery);

        User user;

        while(rs.next())
        {
            user = new User(
                             rs.getInt("id"),
                             rs.getString("fname"),
                             rs.getString("lname"),
                             rs.getInt("age")
                            );
            usersList.add(user);
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return usersList;
}

// function to display data in jtable
public void findUsers()
{
    ArrayList<User> users = ListUsers(jText_Search.getText());
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"ID","Fname","Lname","Age"});
    Object[] row = new Object[4];

    for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
    {
        row[0] = users.get(i).getId();
        row[1] = users.get(i).getFname();
        row[2] = users.get(i).getLname();
        row[3] = users.get(i).getAge();
        model.addRow(row);
    }
   jTable_Users.setModel(model);

}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton_Search = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jText_Search = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable_Users = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton_Search.setText("Search");
    jButton_Search.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton_SearchActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jText_Search.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N

    jTable_Users.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTable_Users.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable_Users);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jText_Search, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 188, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButton_Search)
                    .addGap(136, 136, 136))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 500, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(29, 29, 29))))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton_Search)
                .addComponent(jText_Search, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(41, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>  






// Button Filter/search 

private void jButton_SearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

   findUsers();

}                                              

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JTable_Search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JTable_Search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JTable_Search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JTable_Search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JTable_Search().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton_Search;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable_Users;
private javax.swing.JTextField jText_Search;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

I keep getting an error saying there is an unknown column type. Could someone tell me how I can add the items in the combobox to the array?

Comment: What combobox? What GUI library? Which line causes the error? Can you please post the entire error message word for word? Please have a look at the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help site to see how to improve this and your future questions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you and I just posted the whole code.

Comment: Thank you -- and now the full error message and the involved line?